# Docker does not release port inside container when tomcat service is stopped

Tags: docker, tomcat7

I am building a docker Image with below docker file, the base image already have a tomcat installed.

```
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
 RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
 RUN echo 'root:temp1234' | chpasswd
 RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

 # SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
 RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

 ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
 RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

 EXPOSE 22
 EXPOSE 80
 EXPOSE 443

 CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
 CMD service tomcat7 start && tail -f /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
```

However when I try to run this container it fails with below error

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-16-27-205:~/docker-work$ sudo docker run -p 2222:22 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 d7d7f93692d7

 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
  ...fail!
```

on checking inside container its been found port already in use.

```
root@xxxxbd879:/var/log/tomcat7# sudo netstat -plntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State           PID/Program name
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/sshd
 tcp6       0      0 :::1024                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
 tcp6       0      0 :::44546                :::*                    LISTEN      -
 tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      -
 tcp6       0      0 :::47342                :::*                    LISTEN      -
 tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
 tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN       1/sshd
 tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I am not sure how these ports are occupied.

inside the container as well, I am not able to restart service of tomcat 
it fails with port bind exception.

I thought to kill the the P-ID and start tomcat service however the netstat output is not giving the P-ID of the process.

Kindly suggest how can I start tomcat service on this container

Comment: 1) netstat lists 22, 80 and 443 because they are the ports exposed by container, as for your Dockerfile. 2) Check your original image has not an entrypoint starting Tomcat itself. 3) Look at log files to understand what port is already in use. 4) Having container running sshd and services is not a best practice. I would prefer starting Tomcat by CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"] as Dockerfiles in Docker hub https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/

Comment: 1.) Yes the ports are exposed by Docker file, the netstat output is of container not the docker host.
2.) Original image has tomcat installed but it does not start it.
3.) port 80 and 443 is in use

Comment: Share log messages about the error.

Comment: Dec 13, 2016 4:37:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
Dec 13, 2016 4:37:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)

and similar on port 80

Comment: Can you confirm the network settings for the container in question? `docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks }}' $container_id` may be enough, but a copy/paste of the NeworkSettings section of an unformatted inspect would help.

Comment: sudo docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks }}' 92dab1962c1e

map[bridge:0xc820392000] @BMitch

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is due to CMD attempt to start tomcat as a service (by the way, be careful that Dockerfile runs just the last CMD and in your example you have two CMD lines).
Anyway, try adding a script **run.sh** having this content

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
exec tail -f /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
```

and change your Dockerfile to copy run.sh and give it execution permissions. Then change CMS line in order to execute run.sh (in which you can add command to start sshd too).

```
COPY run.sh /root/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/run.sh
CMD ["/root/run.sh"]
```

Comment: This does able to start tomcat however. if I go inside container stop the service and start it again same issue.

Comment: root@92dab1962c1e:/home/ubuntu/ansible# /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
 * Stopping Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
   ...done.

root@92dab1962c1e:/home/ubuntu/ansible# /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
   ...fail!

Looks like conatiner does not release the port once tomcat service is stop

Comment: My guess is that really "/etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop" doesn't stop tomcat, although it writes "done". Try running a "ps -ef" inside the container after having stopped the container and I'm quite sure you'll have tomcat still running, so ports are already in used. I think "/etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop" doesn't work because it doesn't find "/var/run/tomcat7.pid" having tomcat pid. Anyway, in my opinion you shouldn't use container as virtual machines,so instead of restarting a service inside container, you should run a new container.